# Can I use a dual license in my commercial Website

Tags: licensing, web-applications, gpl, mit-license, commercial

I have set up a web application which is of commercial use. This application had to make use of the plugin(which is not downloaded from http://plugins.jquery.com)
I downloaded this plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2

Kindly, let me know if I could use this plugin in my commercial website.
If I do, would it cause any consequences in future? 
Though, I could see few answers here, I would like to Insist upon itself on this as of critical importance.

[Licensing Terms](http://jquery.malsup.com/license.html)

Comment: -1 for not being able to read the project site. Yes, it's not on the front page, but it took me about 15 seconds to find it.

Comment: @JanHudec sorry about that, but I have read that license and I was not sure about the licensing terms, so asked a question here

Comment: If you've read the paragraph I did, it answered your question rather clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is missing important information: what are the licensing terms for the Cycle2 plugin? The [answer](https://github.com/malsup/cycle2) is that it is available under dual license, MIT and GPL. Which makes this question a duplicate of [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139663/confusion-about-dual-license-mit-gpl-javascript-for-use-on-my-website).

Brief answer: there's no problem using an MIT library in a commercial web website, or any other commercial program.

Therefore there is no problem using a dual licensed library, where one of the options is MIT, in a commercial website. "Dual licensing" means you, as the user, can choose which license to use. You simply make this choice in your own mind, you don't need to tell the library author. Simply say to yourself "I am using MIT", and you're fine.

Comment: added licensing terms

Comment: can I take that "there's no problem using an Dual License(MIT&GPL) in a commercial web website" ?

Comment: @vimal Yes, absolutely.